# spring boot - application start twice..?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am new to spring boot and my application has `Servlet` with eh-cache modules.

```
@EnableCaching 
@SpringBootApplication 
@ServletComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    public Application() {
        log.info("------------------------------");
        log.info("  Welcome to Application");
        log.info("------------------------------");
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

using this, I was trying to start the application, but it starts twice..?

```
        12:11:36,020 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@291e5d10 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
    **2018-03-28_12:11:36.204 com.netapp.prj.Application - ------------------------------
    2018-03-28_12:11:36.226 com.ct.prj.Application -   Welcome to Application
    2018-03-28_12:11:36.226 com.ct.prj.Application - ------------------------------**

      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

    2018-03-28_12:11:40.371 com.ct.prj.Application - Starting Application on NBC02P05-00063 with PID 904 (H:\projects\prj\prj\target\prj\WEB-INF\classes started by   in C:\Balasundaram\Development\eclipse-jee-oxygen-R-win32-x86_64)
    2018-03-28_12:12:00.103 org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Discovered cluster type of STANDALONE
    2018-03-28_12:12:03.505 o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean - Servlet com.ct.prj.config.JerseyConfig mapped to [/services/*]
    2018-03-28_12:12:03.508 o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean - Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
    2018-03-28_12:12:03.509 o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-03-28_12:12:03.509 o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-03-28_12:12:03.509 o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-03-28_12:12:03.510 o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-03-28_12:12:03.510 o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-03-28_12:12:03.511 o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'httpTraceFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-03-28_12:12:03.511 o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
    **2018-03-28_12:12:03.558 com.ct.prj.Application - ------------------------------
    2018-03-28_12:12:03.559 com.ct.prj.Application -   **Welcome to Application**
    2018-03-28_12:12:03.559 com.ct.prj.Application - ------------------------------**
    2018-03-28_12:12:06.952 o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping - Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
```

Please correct me where i am doing mistake..?

Answer (score 8):

The output is coming twice but the application is actually started only once.

There are actually 2 instances going to be created and that is actually due to the [`@SpringBootApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) annotation. Or more precisely the [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) annotation.

When Spring detects a `@Configuration` it will create a special proxy for this class. As this is a class based proxy a new instance will get created to be able to proxy calls to all `@Bean` methods (so that you only get a single instance of the bean etc.). This proxy will wrap the actual instance.

However the `main` class will only run once and the proxied instance will be used to get the `@Bean` methods from.

Comment: Ah, of course - class based proxy-ing of `@Configuration` - forgot about that.

Comment: Actually the `main` method *will* be executed twice.  `main` will be executed once to boot the process and create a proxy, and a second time as the proxy instance to run the application.  So, the application is started once.  But any code in `main` will be executed twice.

Comment: @FlorianF no it won't... The main is only invoked by Java not by the proxy framework. So what you are saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: Obviously "Welcome to Application" gets printed twice.  That is because two instances of `main` get executed.

Comment: No that isn't because two instances of main are executed that is because 2 instances of the bean are created, due to a additional proxy being created.

Answer (score 6):

I was observing the same as I had added a dependency for devtools

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

devtools auto-refresh the context. 
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Only the class `Application` was instatiated twice. The application started up just once.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the dependency for the *spring-boot-devtools* which then made the application startup succesfully.